# How do languages execute main method?

Tags: program-entry-point

I am creating my own programming language for a project and am implementing a scanner, parser, and semantic analyzer. I am wanting this language to be similar to Java or C++ in that they have a method named main that is executed. My grammar allows for a program to consist of 1 or more methods (ideally, the one method would be named `main`), but the syntax just looks for an identifier as the method name. Since main is not a reserved word in Java or C++, how are they able to enforce having a method named main? Having a program without a main method (besides class files or interfaces, where they typically don't) is an error. Is that something that is done in the Semantic analysis portion? Or would that take place later in the linker/loader?

Something else I have always wondered about is how the main method executes first. I know when I write a program that has, for example, 5 methods (one of them being main) that when I run the program, the one that gets executed at the start is main. This is one of those things that I was taught and accepted, and it makes sense as to why that's the case. But, how does the compiler know to execute that particular method from the other ones?

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` ISN'T executed first - there's going to be some boilerplate startup code, that sets up the environment needed for your program to run (initializing global variables, for example).  After the compiler is finished, the linker will be called, specifying this startup file as the very first object file (prior to the object files the compiler generated from your source files).  The startup code gets executed first solely because of this distinguished position in the final executable file; the last thing it will do is call your `main`.  Part of the linker's job is to resolve this reference to the actual function/method named `main`, wherever it might be among the object files.

Lack of a `main` is not a syntax error - it might be defined in a different source file than the one you're currently compiling, after all.  The error would actually result from the linker's inability to resolve that reference from the startup code.

(Please note that I am speaking in extremely general terms, about a whole family of compiled programming languages.  Details will differ between different languages, different implementations of the same language, and between platforms.)